# Convert a 1-dimensional Array of objects (compound type) to a 2-dimensional Array

Tags: arrays, julia

I have defined a compound type like

```
type Position
  Date::DateTime
  x::AbstractFloat
  y::AbstractFloat
  z::AbstractFloat
end
```

and a array 1-dimensional Array of object (compound type) is defined like this

```
arr = [Position(DateTime(2016,1,1,10,00,00),0,0,0),
   Position(DateTime(2016,1,1,10,00,01),2,0,0),
   Position(DateTime(2016,1,1,10,00,02),2,1,0),
   Position(DateTime(2016,1,1,10,00,03),2,2,0),
   ]
```

I can easily get `a_Dates` (array of dates) using

```
a_Dates = map(rec->rec.Date, arr)
```

but I don't know how I can get a 2-dimensional Array of positions (x, y, z)

Ideally I would like a solution without for loop.
For this I know I can do (for example)

```
Nrows, Ncols = length(arr), length(fieldnames(Position)) - 1
data = zeros(Nrows, Ncols)

for i in 1:Nrows
    for j in 1:Ncols
        data[i, j] = getfield(arr[i], j + 1)
    end
end
```

Comment: Why not use a forloop? 
forloops are fastest in julia.

Answer (score 1):

Array

```
new_array = map(rec->[rec.x, rec.y, rec.z], arr)
```

**additionally**

```
new_array = vcat(new_array)
new_array = reshape(new_array,convert(Int64, length(new_array)/3),3)
```

or

```
new_array = reshape(new_array,length(arr),3)
```

Comment: `map(rec->[rec.x, rec.y, rec.z], arr)` returns a `4-element Array{Array{Float64,1},1}` I was expecting a `4x3 Array{Float64,2}`

Comment: oops sorry, added that  for you

Comment: Sorry but it doesn't work here `julia> new_array = vcat(new_array)
4-element Array{Array{Float64,1},1}:
 [0.0,0.0,0.0]
 [2.0,0.0,0.0]
 [2.0,1.0,0.0]
 [2.0,2.0,0.0]

julia> new_array = reshape(new_array, 4,3)
ERROR: DimensionMismatch("new dimensions (4,3) must be consistent with array size 4")
 in reshape at array.jl:146
 in reshape at abstractarray.jl:215`

Comment: the 4 shoulnt be a 4 every time, that varies with the number of vectors

Answer (score 1):

Is `[getfield(p, f) for p in arr, f in (:x, :y, :z)]` what you are looking for?

(In julia 0.4, this will give an `Array{Any}` though, but in this case you could just prefix `Float64` to get the correct type.)